# Wordpress integrate plugin with cimy user extra field plugin

Tags: wordpress

I am currently using cimy user extra field plugin for multi step registration. How can I integrate date picker plugin, facebook like plugin with the plugin that I am currently using.
I have added multiple fields in my registration form. Is it possible to break the form page in multi step pages and a  progressbar to show the user that the registration is going from step 1 to step 2 and so on. Download link of cimy user extra field plugin is http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cimy-user-extra-fields/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First, you should split this into multiple questions. Like, one regarding the date picker, one regarding Facebook, and one regarding the multi-step registration. You're much more likely to get answers that way. Also, it would help to tell us what plugins you're trying to hook together and in what way. In other words, what's the desired functionality when it's all said and done?

Answer (score 0):

To potentially answer your date field question, I would recommend attaching a date picker via jQuery UI, which I think you can so fairly easily via a little JS on the register page. Sounds like you may have to do a little coding there anyway. If you need assistance on getting all that set up, try Google and then come back with anything you can't find or figure out.